# Need help with $\int_0^\infty\arctan\left(e^{-x}\right)\,\arctan\left(e^{-2x}\right)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, closed-form

I was able to calculate:
$$\int_0^\infty\arctan\left(e^{-x}\right)\,dx=G$$
$$\int_0^\infty\arctan^2\left(e^{-x}\right)\,dx=\frac\pi2\,G-\frac78\zeta(3)$$
$G$ is the Catalan constant. In both cases Maple is able to find corresponding indefinite integral, and the above results can be obtained by taking limits. 
They also can be done using identities
$$\arctan\left(e^{-x}\right)=\Im\left(\log\left(1+ie^{-x}\right)\right)\color{gray}{,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}}$$
$$\arctan^2\left(e^{-x}\right)=\frac14\log^2\left(1+e^{-2x}\right)-\Re\left(\log^2\left(1+ie^{-x}\right)\right)\color{gray}{,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}}$$
I'm also interested in this value:
$$\int_0^\infty\arctan\left(e^{-x}\right)\,\arctan\left(e^{-2x}\right)\,dx$$
Could you help me with it? Maple cannot do it.

Comment: Mathematica will grudgingly handle the last one, although the output looks like a huge pile of polylog functions. (It reduces to only a couple of lines of polylog functions at the root of a certain quartic equation, plus some temrs involving the Catalan constant and arcsinh, for low values of 'reduces'.) Maybe it simplifies, but trying to do so directly doesn't yield anything useful. Where does this sort of ugly integral come from?

Comment: Inverse symbolic calculations do not find anything looking like the numerical value $0.25617307025323739218841203901935947736527563268609$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Unfortunately, inverse symbolic calculators are not perfect. See the closed form in my answer below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a fascinating integral!
Following generally the same approach as shown in [David H's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1605911/19661), with help from *Mathematica* and manual simplification using known di- and trilogarithm identities, I was able to establish the following:
$$\int_0^x\arctan\left(e^{-z}\right)\,\arctan\left(e^{-2z}\right)\,dz=x\operatorname{arccot}\left(e^x\right)\operatorname{arccot}\left(e^{2x}\right)\\
+\frac{\pi^2}{32}\left(\vphantom{\Large|}\!\ln\left(1+e^{4x}\right)-10\ln\left(e^{2x}+e^x\sqrt2+1\right)\right)\\
+\frac\pi2\left(\vphantom{\Large|}\!\operatorname{arccot}\left(1+e^x\sqrt2\right)+\arctan\left(e^x\right)\right)\cdot\ln\left(e^{2x}+e^x\sqrt2+1\right)\\
+\frac i4\left\{\left(\vphantom{\Large|}2\operatorname{arccot}\left(e^x\right)+\operatorname{arccot}\left(e^{2x}\right)\right)\cdot\\
\left[\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{(-1)^{3/4}+e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{-(-1)^{1/4}+e^x}{i+e^x}\right)
+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{i-(-1)^{1/4}e^x}{i+e^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{1-(-1)^{1/4}e^x}{1+ie^x}\right)\right]\\
+\left(\vphantom{\Large|}\!\operatorname{arccot}\left(e^{2x}\right)+2\operatorname{arccot}\left(1+e^x\sqrt2\right)-2\operatorname{arccot}\left(e^x\right)\right)\cdot\\
\left[\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{-(-1)^{1/4}+e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{(-1)^{3/4}+e^x}{i+e^x}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{-1+(-1)^{1/4}e^x}{-1+ie^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{-i+(-1)^{1/4}e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)\right]\right\}\\
+\frac i2\left\{\operatorname{arccot}\left(1+e^x\sqrt2\right)\cdot\\
\left[\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{-(-1)^{3/4}+e^x}{i+e^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{(-1)^{1/4}+e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{i+(-1)^{1/4}e^x}{i-e^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{i+(-1)^{3/4}e^x}{i+e^x}\right)\right]+\left(\vphantom{\Large|}\!\operatorname{arccot}\left(e^x\right)-\operatorname{arccot}\left(1+e^x\sqrt2\right)\right)\cdot\left[\vphantom{\Large|}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-(-1)^{1/4}e^x\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1+(-1)^{1/4}e^x\right)\\
+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-(-1)^{3/4}e^x\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1+(-1)^{3/4}e^x\right)\right]\right\}\\
+\frac14\left[\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{-(-1)^{1/4}+e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{-(-1)^{1/4}+e^x}{i+e^x}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{(-1)^{1/4}+e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{(-1)^{1/4}+e^x}{i+e^x}\right)\\
-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{-(-1)^{3/4}+e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{-(-1)^{3/4}+e^x}{i+e^x}\right)
-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{(-1)^{3/4}+e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{(-1)^{3/4}+e^x}{i+e^x}\right)\\
+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{i-(-1)^{1/4}e^x}{i+e^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{-1+(-1)^{1/4}e^x}{-1+ie^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{-i+(-1)^{1/4}e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\tfrac{i+(-1)^{1/4}e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)\\
+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{i+(-1)^{1/4}e^x}{i+e^x}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{-i+(-1)^{3/4}e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\tfrac{i+(-1)^{3/4}e^x}{-i+e^x}\right)
-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{i+(-1)^{3/4}e^x}{i+e^x}\right)\right]\\
+\frac\pi{64}\left[\left(2+\sqrt2\right)\cdot\left(16G+\pi^2\sqrt2\right)-\sqrt2\,\psi^{(1)}\!\left(\tfrac18\right)\right]$$
([here](http://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/947f0abc92c0aa8c8d06/raw/0908834400a389e4c7d9c99c0451dbae5caa6073/ArcTan.nb) is the corresponding *Mathematica* expression)

If I'm not mistaken, it must hold for all real $x$, and might hold for some complex $x$, but in general there are some branch cuts that need to be dealt with (I was not yet able to analyze them completely). A possible proof consists of taking a derivative, a (tedious) simplification and computing a limit to establish the constant of integration. I relied on *Mathematica* for some steps, followed by high-precision numerical validation.

So, the final answer is

> $$\int_0^\infty\arctan\left(e^{-x}\right)\,\arctan\left(e^{-2x}\right)\,dx=\frac\pi{64}\left[\left(2+\sqrt2\right)\cdot\left(16G+\pi^2\sqrt2\right)-\sqrt2\,\psi^{(1)}\!\left(\tfrac18\right)\right]$$

Comment: inverse symbolic calculators are not perfect, for sure .... but ... you are !

Comment: I wonder if the antiderivative could be simplified. I feel that possibly the number of polylogarithm terms and complex numbers can be reduced if we put to work $\operatorname{Cl}_n(z)$ and $\operatorname{Ti}_n(z)$. Unfortunately, _Mathematica_ does not have native support for these functions.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov +1) The final value you found is much tidier than I was anticipating! In general, the reduction of logarithmic integrals of the form $\int\frac{\ln{(1+ax)}\ln{(1+bx)}}{x}dx$ will produce five trilogarithmic terms prior to simplification. Regarding the integral in the OP, I managed to reduce it to a sum of four logarithmic integrals, meaning $4\times5=20$ trilogs! This is part of the reason I gave up on finishing my answer. :)

Answer (score 9):

We'll have use for the following trigonometric identity, which may be verified by the well-known arctangent addition law:

$$\small{\arctan{\left(x^{2}\right)}=\arctan{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}-x}\right)}-\arctan{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}+x}\right)}};~~~\small{\left|x\right|<\sqrt{2}}.$$

We'll also need the definition of the arctangent function in terms of complex logarithms:

$$\arctan{\left(z\right)}=\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}\right)}}{2i}.$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\arctan{\left(e^{-y}\right)}\arctan{\left(e^{-2y}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan{\left(x\right)}\arctan{\left(x^{2}\right)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x;~~~\small{\left[e^{-y}=x\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan{\left(x\right)}\left[\arctan{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}-x}\right)}-\arctan{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}+x}\right)}\right]}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan{\left(x\right)}\left[\ln{\left(1-e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}x\right)}-\ln{\left(1-e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}x\right)}\right]}{2ix}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan{\left(x\right)}\left[\ln{\left(1+e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}x\right)}-\ln{\left(1+e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}x\right)}\right]}{2ix}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\small{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left[\ln{\left(1+ix\right)}-\ln{\left(1-ix\right)}\right]\left[\ln{\left(1+e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}x\right)}-\ln{\left(1+e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}x\right)}\right]}{4x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&~~~~~\small{-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left[\ln{\left(1+ix\right)}-\ln{\left(1-ix\right)}\right]\left[\ln{\left(1+e^{\frac{3i\pi}{4}}x\right)}-\ln{\left(1+e^{-\frac{3i\pi}{4}}x\right)}\right]}{4x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=\small{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\Re{\left[\ln{\left(1+ix\right)}\ln{\left(1+e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}x\right)}-\ln{\left(1-ix\right)}\ln{\left(1+e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}x\right)}\right]}}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&~~~~~\small{-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\Re{\left[\ln{\left(1+ix\right)}\ln{\left(1+e^{\frac{3i\pi}{4}}x\right)}-\ln{\left(1-ix\right)}\ln{\left(1+e^{\frac{3i\pi}{4}}x\right)}\right]}}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x}.\\
\end{align}$$

Any integral of the form $\int\frac{\ln{\left(ax+b\right)}\ln{\left(cx+d\right)}}{px+q}\,\mathrm{d}x$ can be systematically reduced to trilogarithms, dilogarithms, and elementary functions. Thus, we recognize that $I$ can be decomposed into a sum of such integrals, and so in principle we are done except for the tedium.

Answer (score 4):

Let $I$ denotes your integral, $C$ denotes **Catalan's constant**.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(x)\arctan(x^2)}{x} \text{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(x)\arctan(\sqrt{x} )}{x}\text{d}x\\
&= \frac{\pi C}{8}-\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\operatorname{Ti}_2(x)}{\sqrt{x}(1+x) } \text{d}x\\
&=\frac{3\pi C}{8}-\frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Ti}_2(x)}{\sqrt{x}(1+x) } \text{d}x\\
&=\frac{3\pi C}{8}-\frac{1}{8}\underbrace{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Ti}_2(x^2)}{1+x^2 } \text{d}x}_{J}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Notice that $\operatorname{Ti}_2(x^2)=\Im\operatorname{Li}_2(ix^2)$. And $\operatorname{Li}_2(iz^2)
=2 \left (
\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{\pi i/4}z)
+\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{\pi i/4}z)  \right ).$
So
$$
J=2\Im\left ( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{\pi i/4}z)
+\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{\pi i/4}z)}{1+z^2}\text{d}z  \right ).
$$
Consider the functions
$$
f(z)=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{\pi i/4}z)}{1+z^2} ,
f^{\prime}(z)
=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{\pi i/4}z)}{1+z^2}.
$$
$f(z),f'(z)$ have two branch points in the lower half plane and upper half plane, respectively. Now we construct two very large semicircles in upper and lower half plane such that $f(z),f'(z)$ are meromorphic in the interiors. By Cauchy residue theorem,
$$
J=4\pi\Im\left ( 
\operatorname{Li}_2(ie^{\pi i/4}) \right ).
$$
And
$$I=\frac{3\pi C}{8}-\frac{\pi}{2} \Im\left ( 
\operatorname{Li}_2(ie^{\pi i/4}) \right ).$$
Therefore $I$ is evaluated as
$$I=\frac{\pi C}{2} 
-\frac{\pi\left ( \psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{1}{8}  \right )
+\psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{3}{8}  \right ) 
-\psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{5}{8}  \right ) 
-\psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{7}{8}  \right )\right ) }{128\sqrt{2} }$$
where $\psi^{(1)}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+z)^2}$ is the derivative of digamma function $\psi^{(0)}(z)$.

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution within real analysis by hand that avoids polylogarithms
$$I=\int_0^\infty\arctan(e^{-x})\arctan(e^{-2x})dx=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\arctan x^2 }{x}dx$$
Integrate by parts with $u=\arctan x\arctan x^2$ and $dv=\frac{dx}{x}$
$$I=-\int_0^1\left(\frac{2x\ln x\arctan x}{x^4+1}+\frac{\ln x\arctan x^2}{x^2+1}\right)dx=-2J-K$$
Start with J. We invert the integral with $u=\frac{1}{x}$, then add two versions of J. Then, isolate $J$
$$J=\int_0^1\frac{x\ln x\arctan x}{x^4+1}dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{x\ln x   \left(\arctan x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{x^4+1}dx$$
$$2J=-\frac{\pi G}{8}+\int_0^\infty\frac{x\ln x\arctan x}{x^4+1}dx$$
$$J=\frac{-\pi G}{16}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{x\ln x \arctan x}{x^4+1}dx$$
This gives an improper integral. Substitute an integral representation of the inverse tangent function, and apply Fubini's theorem.
$$=\frac{-\pi G}{16}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{x\ln x}{x^4+1}\left(\int_0^1\frac{x}{x^2y^2+1}dy\right)dx$$
$$=\frac{-\pi G}{16}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln x}{(x^2y^2+1)(x^4+1)}dx\space dy$$
Evaluate the inside integral separately with partial fractions
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln x}{(x^2y^2+1)(x^4+1)}dx=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{y^2}{y^4+1}\frac{1}{x^4+1}+\frac{1}{y^4+1}\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}-\frac{y^2}{y^4+1}\frac{1}{x^2y^2+1}\right)\ln x \space dx$$$$=-\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\frac{y^2}{y^4+1}+\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\frac{1}{y^4+1}-\frac{y}{y^4+1}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2y^2+1}y\space dx$$
Substitute $x→\frac{x}{y}$
$$=-\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\frac{y^2}{y^4+1}+\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\frac{1}{y^4+1}-\frac{y}{y^4+1}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x-\ln y}{x^2+1}\space dx$$$$=-\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\frac{y^2}{y^4+1}+\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\frac{1}{y^4+1}+\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{y\ln{y}}{y^4+1}$$
Plug back into the equation for $J$
$$J=\frac{-\pi G}{16}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\frac{y^2}{y^4+1}+\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\frac{1}{y^4+1}+\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{y\ln{y}}{y^4+1}\right)dy$$$$=\frac{-\pi G}{16}-\frac{\pi^2}{16\sqrt2}\left(\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt2}+\frac{\ln(\sqrt2-1)}{2\sqrt2}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{16\sqrt2}\left( \frac{\pi}{4\sqrt2}+\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt2)}{2\sqrt2} \right)+\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\frac{-G}{4}\right)$$$$=\frac{-\pi G}{8}+\frac{\pi^2\ln(1+\sqrt2)}{32}$$
Moving on to K. We can apply the same method. Invert, add 2 versions, isolate $K$
$$K=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x \arctan x^2}{x^2+1}dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln x (\arctan x^2-\frac{\pi}{2})}{x^2+1}dx$$
$$2K=\frac{-\pi G}{2}+\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x\arctan x^2}{x^2+1}dx$$$$K=\frac{-\pi G}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x\arctan x^2}{x^2+1}dx$$
Insert an integral representation for $\arctan{x^2}$ and apply Fubini's theorem$$=\frac{-\pi G}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}\left(\int_0^1\frac{2x^2y}{x^4y^4+1}dy\right)dx$$$$=\frac{-\pi G}{4}+\int_0^1\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2y\ln{x}}{(x^4y^4+1)(x^2+1)}dx\space dy$$
Evaluate the inside integral separately. Apply partial fractions, substitute $x→\frac{x}{y}$, distribute, and integrate term-by-term
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2y\ln{x}}{(x^4y^4+1)(x^2+1)}dx=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{y^5}{y^4+1}\frac{x^2}{x^4y^4+1}+\frac{y}{y^4+1}\frac{1}{x^4y^4+1}-\frac{y}{y^4+1}\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)\ln x\space dx$$$$=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{y^2}{y^4+1}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4y^4+1}+\frac{1}{y^4+1}\frac{1}{x^4y^4+1}\right)y\ln x\space dx$$$$=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{y^2}{y^4+1}\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}+\frac{1}{y^4+1}\frac{1}{x^4+1}\right)(\ln x-\ln y)dx=\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\frac{y^2-1}{y^4+1}-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}\frac{y^2+1}{y^4+1}\ln y$$
Plug it back into the equation for $K$
$$K=\frac{-\pi G}{4}+\int_0^1\left(\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\frac{y^2-1}{y^4+1}-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}\frac{y^2+1}{y^4+1}\ln y\right)dy$$$$=\frac{-\pi G}{4}+\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\frac{\ln(\sqrt2-1)}{\sqrt2}-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}\int_0^1\frac{y^2+1}{y^4+1}\ln y\space dy$$
Evaluate the integral on the right-hand side separately. Apply geometric series, integrate the series term-by-term, and apply the definition of the trigamma function.
$$\int_0^1\frac{y^2+1}{y^4+1}\ln y\space dy=\int_0^1\frac{1+y^2-y^4-y^6}{1-y^8}\ln y \space dy$$$$=\int_0^1(1+y^2-y^4-y^6)\ln y\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^{8n}dy$$$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1(y^{8n}+y^{8n+2}-y^{8n+4}-y^{8n+6})\ln y\space  dy$$$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(8n+7)^2}+\frac{1}{(8n+5)^2}-\frac{1}{(8n+3)^2}-\frac{1}{(8n+1)^2}\right)$$$$=\frac{\psi\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)+\psi\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)}{64}$$
Plug it back into the equation for $K$
$$K=\frac{-\pi G}{4}+\frac{\pi^2\ln(\sqrt2-1)}{16}-\frac{\pi}{128\sqrt2}\left({\psi\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)+\psi\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)}\right)$$
Plug $J$ and $K$ back into the equation for $I$
$$I=-2J-K$$$$=-2\left(\frac{-\pi G}{8}+\frac{\pi^2\ln(1+\sqrt2)}{32}\right)-\left(\frac{-\pi G}{4}+\frac{\pi^2\ln(\sqrt2-1)}{16}-\frac{\pi}{128\sqrt2}\left({\psi\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)+\psi\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)}\right)\right)$$$$=\frac{\pi G}{2}+\frac{\pi}{128\sqrt2}\left({\psi\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)+\psi\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)}\right)$$
Final answer:
$$I=\int_0^\infty\arctan(e^{-x})\arctan(e^{-2x})dx=\frac{\pi G}{2}+\frac{\pi}{128\sqrt2}\left({\psi\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)+\psi\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)}\right)$$
We also have $$J=\int_0^1\frac{x\ln x\arctan x}{x^4+1}dx=\frac{-\pi G}{8}+\frac{\pi^2}{32}\ln(1+\sqrt2)$$
$$K=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\arctan x^2}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{-\pi G}{4}+\frac{\pi^2\ln(\sqrt2-1)}{16}-\frac{\pi}{128\sqrt2}\left({\psi\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)+\psi\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Using the series for arctan, it is 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(2i+1)(4j+2)(2i+4j+3)}$$

Answer (score 2):

> **Too long for a comment :**

As far as *definite* integrals are concerned, there are no currently known methods of actually proving that they do not possess a closed form. $($ In other words, there are no equivalents of [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) or the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for *definite* integrals $).$ So what I'm about to write 
 does not constitute “proof” of anything, but serves merely as an *intuitive* explanation for why 
 it is *unlikely* that the integral you posted to have a “meaningful” closed form. Notice that the 
 other two integrands possess an inverse, i.e., $$y~=~\arctan^n(e^{-x})~\iff~x~=~-\ln\tan\sqrt[n]y~=~\ln\cos\sqrt[n]y~-~\ln\sin\sqrt[n]y~.$$ At the same time, remember the well-known [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) between the definite integral of a function, and that of its inverse:

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ [image]

Applying it to the former two cases, it yields something *manageable*, following a substitution of the form $y=t^n.$ The latter integrand, however, does not exhibit such auspicious traits, since its inverse cannot be expressed in terms of any known functions, be they either special or elementary.